# Excel VBA conditional cumulative sum problem

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am very new to VBA and have a problem in excel.

According to the image, I have to place a value in each cell of column V meeting the following criteria:

- Values in V <= Values in T
- Sum of values in T = DEMAND

[image]

I already tried Excel Solver but I have to do this for 120,000 tables and applying solver takes too much time. I am expecting to use a macro VBA or just formulas if possible but don't know how to.

Comment: [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) ?

Comment: No need for solver here.  Fill V using values from T until sum(V) >= Demand.  Reduce last-added value in V by the difference between the sum(V) and demand.

Comment: Is your picture a 'before' or 'after' illustration?  If zero is an acceptable value, then what @Tim Williams described works just fine.  Reduce your last entry by 70¢ and it meets all your described constraints.  If zero is not an acceptable value, then there are probably some other constraints about the distribution you will want to include.